# How to remove same dropdown value in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know this might sound like a simple question -- I have this dropdown, let's say that when I save value 'Q' into the table, when I want to change from this drop down to value 'C', I can't because it shows me the value 'Q' twice in the dropdown.

```
<td><asp:Label ID="lblQ" runat="server" >Type</asp:Label></td>
     <td>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQ" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="254px">
     <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Q" Value="Q"></asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>

 </td>
```

In my aspx.vb I am using something like this, is this the right way?

```
strQ = ""

ddlQ.SelectedItem.Text = strQ
```

Comment: unclear what you are asking...the markup you have shown doesn't include the value `Q` twice. Are you asking how to clear the selected dropdown value? Or set it to something else?

Comment: yeah..if let say i have already selected the Q, i would expect the next time i want to change the value, i will see C..is that possible?however my current situation keep showing 2 Q.